# Greater than or Equal to Report Parameter functionality SSRS 2012 and SSAS 2008 cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssas-2008

I have an SSRS 2012 report and SSAS Cube in 2008. My report criterion requires filtering on measures. So Created measures as dimensions . The report requires >= functionality on the measures. But in the Query designer of  the report there is =, IN, Within Range ,Excluding range , MDX as the operators.
To achieve my goal. I have “From” and “To” as parameters on the numeric dimension. The “To” parameter I have set as internal and setting  the default value of  “TO” .By writing another Dataset query that returns the “MAX”  value and the MAX value returned is a member of the measure converted to dim I confirmed.. So this whole works as >=.The user enters only the “FROM” parameter and the “TO” is set internally. The user can enter any value in the “From” parameter. Any value that is not even a member.It is a textbox. I cannot use a list of values from the “From” parameter.
But whenever I run the report after entering all the selection criteria  I keep getting 
Error “the restrictions imposed by the constrained flag in the strtomember functions were violated”
I know this means that Max value in the “TO” section is not a member .
I did try : StrToMember("[Fact RCS CV BLAST].[APPRLIMIT ACH].
&[" & @ToFactRCSCVBLASTAPPRLIMITACH & "]", CONSTRAINED) ) 
 But I get “syntax for the “&” is incorrect”

If I use Drop down for the “From” and “To” parameters then it works fine. But that’s not what Business Users need. 
Please let me know what the options to make this work. I did use parameters that filter the  Dataset returned it works fine but there is a performance impact.

Comment: Your question is so difficult to understand, I don't even know what to suggest to help you make it more readable.   It looks like it has a lot of irrelevant details.  Maybe you can shorten it to just a simple "how do I do X?" question?   Maybe some code/data/DDL examples might help.

Comment: Can you restrict your textbox to only contain numbers? Then, I think `Filter` would help you, and you would not need any "measure dimension". But to be able to answer more detailed, I would need to see the current query, and a concrete description of the `>=` restriction based on this query.